# SLSQP yields complete different - vs COBYLA

Tags: python, optimization, openmdao

Why does SLSQP gets stuck around the initial values, while COBYLA moves towards 
the right direction ?

Optimization Problem is implemented using OpenMDAO 2.2.X;

3 design variables --> input to external code comp --> that outputs y which is
the objective(y, scaler=-1). There are no constraints.

The plot below shows the behavior of the two optimizer for the same problem. I have tried to change the finite difference setup of the SLSQP but it did not help. The output is Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0).

The sample driver and wrapper codes are uploaded:
https://gist.github.com/stackoverflow38/0219eda12d4c56ce84c68d201d1f1926

[image: comparison of the same setup]

Comment: What is the status-output of those solvers? Never trust anything without reading those out (except you are sure your lib will raise an exception in any state but success).

Comment: Do you mean the status output such as this right ? This is SLSQP
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: -27272708.4836453
            Iterations: 5
            Function evaluations: 49
            Gradient evaluations: 5
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see anything obviously wrong with your problem setup, but without `gf_run.py` its not possible to run the model you've provided to test it out. So in lieu of that, the best guess I can give you is one of the following options:

1) COBYLA is a gradient free optimizer that has a bit more ability to search over the design space. Perhaps its finding a a different optimum, while SLSQP is getting stuck at a lesser optimum near the starting point. To test this, you can use the result from COBYLA as the initial guess for SLSQP. If SLSQP converges to the same (or close to the same) point as COBYLA then, its likely a local-optimum problem.

2) SLSQP uses gradients, which you are approximating using central difference. Those derivative approximations could be poor, even using the 2nd order central differencing. Its not clear if the underlying code has some kind of an implicit solver in it (like a newton solver or a while-loop convergence). If it does have some kind of internal solver, then you need to make sure the tolerance is set pretty tight--- at least two order of magnitude lower than your FD step size would be preferable. Even then, it simply may not be possible to get a quality FD approximation around an code with a solver in it. You could also try changing the FD step size a bit.

Comment: I could not upload the external code as it requires license to run. I am using Python to call the terminal and run that code. I thought of your number 1 suggestion in the beginning and played around with the initial guess, did not help. But I will now check more thoroughly if that is the issue. Because the second one seems to me more unlikely but i will also adjust the FD step size. Of course this whole thing might arise the question whether the gradient based optimizer ends up being slower than the gradient-free optimizer. as the number of design variables are small. this may be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason was that FD steps were too small that the gradients were inaccurate. I have used so far steps of 1e-3 to 1e-6. And now I use 1, the optimizer did not get stuck with step of 1 for all design variables. I am guessing that the difference in the output of the external code was very small with small FD steps (1e-3) such that the optimizer did not calculate the gradient accurately.